# Why is JVM not instancing new TimerTask when using timer.schedule()?

Tags: java, android

I have a Timer in my Code, but the debugger jumps not into it. When it arrives at "timer.schedule()", jumps directly behind it and is not instancing the anonymous TimerTask. Can anyone help me why?

CODE:

```
timer = new Timer();

lastTimestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
```

// WHEN DEBUGGING IT JUMPS FROM THIS LINE

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
            secondsElapsed += now - lastTimestamp;
            lastTimestamp = now;
            // Abbruch-Bedingung
            if(secondsElapsed == totalSeconds)
            {
                // TODO:
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Zeit abgelaufen");
            }
            else
            {
                int minutes = (int)secondsElapsed / 60;
                int seconds = secondsElapsed - (minutes * 60);
                final String newValue = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timerText.setText(newValue);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

// TO THIS LINE

Comment: If the answer helped you, it would be nice to accept it. It creates goodwill

Comment: What timer import do you use? javax.swing or java.util?

Comment: java.util It is the only class that matches the rest of the methods used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lines are executing in another thread. When that thread is scheduled to run they will run. If you place a breakpoint there you will see them execute

**EDIT**

```
try {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

         long lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        // WHEN DEBUGGING IT JUMPS FROM THIS LINE

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("WWWWWWW");
                }
            }, 0, 1000);    
    }
    catch(Exception x){

    }
}
```

This code executes with no problem. The thread is executed inside the timer

Comment: if you are using intellij or another ide you will see in one of the debugging tabs the different threads running, you would have to switch to it. At least in eclipse, you have to do this. Does it run/log you messages?

Comment: None of the Code inside the run-Method is performed

Comment: Taken the Snippet into a new Project and pasted the other Surroundings to this Project. It's running. Don't know why, everything of the Code from the timer-part is the same like the other Project, which is not performing the scheduled task...